# Check for all NULLs within a group

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

Find if a specific column in a group are all NULLs, then populate the target accordingly. I have a record-set as given below. My requirement is to populate the output column "total" based on -
1) Within a group (or Partition) if the "trans_dt" column in all the rows are NULLs, then populate "total" column in the output as zer0
2) If any of the records has a valid value (in trans_dt column) then populate the "total" with the max value of "items" for that that group and the trans_dt as the MAX trans_dt for that group

```
custid|transact_dt|items  
------------------------  
1234|05/01/2019|3  
1234|10/02/2019|4  
1234|Null|3  
5678|Null|5  
5678|Null|3  
5678|Null|1  
5678|Null|2
```

In the above record-set custid "1234" has valid values in trans_dt in 2 rows, hence the output column "total" should be populated as "4". However, for custid "5678", all trans_dt values are Nulls, hence "total" should be populated as 0.

```
custid|transact_dt|items  
------------------------  
1234|10/02/2019|4  
5678|31/12/9999|0
```

```
select custid, max_trans_dt, 
CASE WHEN max_trans_dt IS NULL then 0
ELSE total  
END as total
from 
( select custid, MAX(trans_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY custid) as max_trans_dt, MAX(items) OVER (PARTITION BY custid) as total,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custid order by trans_dt desc, items desc) as rn ) tmp
WHERE tmp.rn = 1
```

Is there a smarter and cleaner solution to the above requirement ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select cust_id
       max(case when trans_dt is not null then items else 0 end) as max_items
from t
group by cust_id;
```

Comment: @RishiChowdhury if the answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.